# How can I pass attributes of an SVG element to a new event in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to return the value of the "class" and "subtasks" attributes of a rectangle when I click on the mouse in D3.

```
var projectRectangles = rectangles.append("rect")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return (d)[7]; })
    .attr("class", function(d) { return (d)[3]; })
    .attr("subtasks", function(d) { return (d)[4]; })
    .on("click", function() {expandTasks(this.id, this.class, this.subtask); });

function expandTasks(task_id, task_subtasks, task_class) { alert(task_id + '/' + task_subtasks + '/' + task_class);};
```

Sample response: 1/undefined/undefined

It returns *this.id* fine but *this.class* and *this.subtasks* always return "undefined". 'class' and 'subtasks' appear fine in the attributes of the  so why does it work for id, but not for the others?

Ultimately, of course, I'd like to know the best way to pass these attributes on to another function.

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the class and subtasks attributes as shown in below code inside the click listener.

```
d3.select(this).attr("class");
d3.select(this).attr("subtasks");
```

You may also use `this.className` to get the class attribute. But since `subtasks` is a custom attribute, you will have to get it use the d3 `attr` method or html `getAttribute` method.

To pass the attributes to some other functions from click listener, try any of the methods shown below.

> The parameter d gives the data object binded to the corresponding
>   element.

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    expandTasks(d[7],d[3],d[4]); 
});
```

or

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var id = d3.select(this).attr("id"); // or this.id
    var className = d3.select(this).attr("class");// or this.className
    var subtasks = d3.select(this).attr("subtasks"); // or this.getAttribute("subtasks");
    expandTasks(id,className,subtasks); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much... why didn't I think of asking the question 4 hours ago instead of searching fruitlessly. A really informative and helpful answer :-)

Comment: Glad it is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers that solve your immediate problem, note that it could be worth it to remap your data prior to joining it to your selection. Something like

```
var rectangles = pad
                 .selectAll("rect")
                 .data(data.map(function(d) {
                        return {
                            id: d[7],
                            classname: d[3],
                            subtask: d[4]
                        };
                  }));
```

where your transform your (presumed) arrays into objects with understandable keys.

You could then rewrite your attributes assignments and your handler as

```
var projectRectangles = rectangles.append("rect")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.classname; })
        .on("click", function(d) {
            expandTasks(d.id, d.classname, d.subtask);
        });
```

And a demo

```js
var data = [
    [null, null, null, 'class1', 'subtasks1', null, null, 'id1'],
    [null, null, null, 'class2', 'subtasks2', null, null, 'id2']
];

var expandTasks = function() {
    alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '))
};

var pad = d3.select('body').append('svg').append("g");
var rectangles = pad.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data.map(function(d) {
                            return {
                                id: d[7],
                                classname: d[3],
                                subtask: d[4]
                            };
                    }))


var projectRectangles = rectangles.enter().append("rect")
    .attr('x',function(d, i) {return i*100;})
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',100).attr('height',100)
        .attr("class", function(d) { return d.classname; })
        .on("click", function(d) {
            expandTasks(d.id, d.classname, d.subtask);
        });
```

```css
svg {background-color: beige; width:200px; height:100px}
.class1 {fill: red}
.class2 {fill: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - had never come across the map function. I admit to having been rather lazy in not naming my data initially, but the map function is very helpful for instances where I'm running with unspecified data.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in how you access the attributes of your `rect`. As you want to have more flexibility in getting the attributes to another function, may I propose the following:

Replace your `on` event with the following line:

```
.on("click", function() {expandTasks(d3.select(this)); });
```

And you `expandTasks` method with this one:

```
function expandTasks(d) { 
   alert(d.attr("id") + '/' + d.attr("class") + '/' + d.attr("subtasks"));
};
```

Essentially you are passing the `g` element to the `expandTasks` method, and then you can access any parameter of the element using `d.attr(****)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another great answer from a different perspective. Thanks.